# ‎mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' in else if in pinescript with rsi

Tags: pine-script, trading

```
if (rsi < 30)
    strategy.entry("RSI Buy", true, stop=strategy.price * (1 - stopLoss), limit=strategy.price * (1 + takeProfit))
    plotchar("Leverage Recommendation", "For this buy signal, it is recommended to use low leverage (e.g. 2x or 3x) to minimize risk.")
else if (rsi > 70)
    strategy.entry("RSI Sell", false, stop=strategy.price * (1 + stopLoss), limit=strategy.price * (1 - takeProfit))
    plotchar("Leverage Recommendation", "For this sell signal, it is recommended to use high leverage (e.g. 10x or 20x) to maximize profits.")
```

I dont know what should I do everytime it gives me the error: ‎mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'‎ in the else if statement... not in if but in else if why? what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `plotchar()` in a local scope. Use [label](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html) instead.

Comment: not working still the same error

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.